# pip install wxPython gets the cores at 95 C

Tags: compiling, pip, wxpython

Running on terminal the command `pip install wxPython` gets to build the wheel and it takes long while rocketing the cores temp to 95C. What should I do?

```
$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               user@precision-3551 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Precision 3551 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-79-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 2 days, 21 hours, 13 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 3100 (dpkg), 19 (flatpak), 39 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.0.17 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Nordic 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Nordic [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-10850H (12) @ 2.700GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA Quadro P620 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 9489MiB / 15591MiB
```

Here are the other specs:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d000006A3sv00001028sd000009C2bc0Csc05i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
driver   : oem-beaver-osp1-bowen-meta - third-party free
driver   : oem-somerville-bowen-meta - distro free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001CBDsv00001028sd000009C2bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107GLM [Quadro P620]
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id ==
modalias : dmi:bvnDellInc.:bvr1.14.0:bd06/13/2022:br1.14:svnDellInc.:pnPrecision3551:pvr:rvnDellInc.:rn0M21VD:rvrA00:cvnDellInc.:ct10:cvr:sku09C2:
driver   : oem-kernel-parameter-suspend-to-ram - third-party free
driver   : oem-seventy-percent-brightness - third-party free
driver   : dell-service-meta - third-party free
driver   : oem-release - third-party free
```

Comment: This may be caused by a hardware issue. Please edit your question and list your computer's specs.

Comment: @karel what's a command to list what is needed here?

Comment: The command is `sudo apt install neofetch && neofetch`

Comment: @karel, thanks, edited!

Comment: The NVIDIA Quadro P620 graphics sticks out as a potential problem. What are the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended` ? What are the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` ?

Comment: @Psionman, thanks, I've added the specs. What do you mean that the P620 graphics can be a potential problem?

Comment: That's why I asked you for  the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices` in the preceding comment. I want to check if there are any available drivers for the NVIDIA Quadro P620 graphics card.

Comment: Not related to the thermal issue - Do you know that `pip` would install `wxPython` for the discontinued `python2`? If you want wxPython for `python3`, use `pip3 install wxPython` instead.

Comment: Your processor was released in 2020. The older kernel of Ubuntu 20.04 may not support it very well. Try Ubuntu 22.04, and check if the heating issue is still present there.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, ok I have upgraded to 22.04 and the same issue holds.